# How to join two table id and validate a particular field?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Sorry for the fuorviant title but I'll trying to explain what I'm try to do. So, I've two table `ea_users` and `ea_user_settings`.

**ea_users - STRUCTURE**

```
id  | data|
5 | 0
```

**ea_user_settings - STRUCTURE**

```
|id | username|
 5    Sandokan
```

Now what I'm trying to do is validate if certain username already exists in the system. The table `ea_users` contain the id, that rapresents the `id` of a single user, and the `data` field (0 user not removed, also 1 user deleted).

In the `ea_user_settings` table I've all settings of my users. Now a possible idea for check if a certain username already exist is this:

```
public function validate_username($username, $user_id)
{
    $num_rows = $this->db->get_where('ea_user_settings',
        array('username' => $username, 'id_users <> ' => $user_id))->num_rows();
    return ($num_rows > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

This function have two parameters: `username` and `user_id`, the `username` that's going to be inserted and the `user_id` (if this is valorized means that I'm actually stay update the user so I don't need to check on it row if the username already exists).
Actually all working good but I want to check if the `username` exists for only the user with the data equal to 0, if the data is 1 the username is available 'cause it's deleted. I don't know if the situation is more clear. How I can achieve that in  a single query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
public function validate_username($username, $user_id)
{
        $num_rows =
        $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('ea_user_settings')
        ->join('ea_users', 'ea_user_settings.id_users = ea_users.id', 'left')
        ->where(array('ea_user_settings.username' => $username, 'ea_user_settings.id_users <> ' => $user_id, 'ea_users.data' => 1))
        ->get();
        return ($num_rows->num_rows() > 0) ? 'We have this username and it was deleted!' : 'This username was not deleted';
}
```

Comment: Ok for the data = 1 working but if I insert an username that doesn't exists in the db the query return false.

Comment: @Sandokan can you explain what you are trying to check? of course if it doesn't exist it will return false because our query checks for this spesific username

Comment: @IlanHasanov I guess the user need to check if the username exists for the not deleted user (data = 0), so maybe in your query you should change ea_users.data to 0 and set the return false in the first step not in the second. It's right?